Expect script frozen when appending output to nohup.out
This is the first time I have done an expect script.
In principle it is a simple script
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 200

spawn XXX/bin/PROGRAM

expect "Choose an option ..."
send "1\r"

...

The program has several options, and I have made 4 similar scripts with them that have not given problems, in addition, in the option that gives problems I also navigate through a series of submenus without problems.
The problem appears at a certain point when the program I have spawned throws the message:
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'

The problem always occurs in an expect-send block where the program kills a number of processes.
When I run the program directly from the command line I don't get this problem, so I understand that the problem is related to the output directioning of the process created by spawn, I have tried several ways to solve this but all without success.
How can I make the process created by the expect script behave in the same way as in my terminal and avoid the redirecting to nohup?
Thank you very much.

That's not an error. It's the normal output when you use the nohup command.

But I don't use nohup. And looking at the behaviour of the program when I run it from the terminal I understand that it doesn't either.
Unless spawn uses it, it is not used directly.

Most likely it's the spawned program that does it. It may have different behaviours if it detects it's not connected to a "real" terminal.

I managed to find a solution and I answer myself.
The error was indeed in the process that the script created for the program, because as I said it behaved differently (someone commented that this is what happened too).
To solve it I simply spawned a terminal, and from the terminal I launched the program, so the behaviour is the same.
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 200

spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000

send -- "XXX/bin/PROGRAM\r"

expect "Choose an option ..."
send "1\r"

...

I hope this helps if you encounter a similar problem.
